# NullPointerException When Loading Objects Into A ListView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm attempting to do some mock-ups of a UI of an application that I'm building. I'm using a Navigation drawer as the root layout and I'm using nested fragments for one of my menu items in order to use a ViewPager with tab indicators. That part works fine when I just populate each of the fragments with just some basic text, but when I replaced the basic text in one of the children fragments (one of the tab views) with a ListView; I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException in my fragment class.

```
public class FragmentVenues extends ListFragment {

private static final String ARGUMENT_KEY_PROPERTIES = "venue";


public static FragmentVenues newInstance(ArrayList<Venue> venues) {
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(ARGUMENT_KEY_PROPERTIES, venues);

    final FragmentVenues f = new FragmentVenues();
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final List<Venue> venues =      getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARGUMENT_KEY_PROPERTIES);//error here
    setListAdapter(new VenueListAdapter(getActivity(), venues));
}
```

This is the ListAdapter that accesses a class that fills creates the objects to load into the ListView.

```
public class VenueListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Venue>{
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public VenueListAdapter(Context context, List<Venue> objects) {
    super(context, -1, objects);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Venue venue = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentvenues, parent, false);
    }

    // This will be made more efficient later
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    tv.setText(venue.getCity() + ", " + venue.getState());
    tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venuename);
    tv.setText(venue.getVenueName());
    tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.street);
    tv.setText(venue.getStreetAddress());
    tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
    tv.setText(venue.getPhoneNumber());

    return convertView;

}
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and/or if there's something I'm missing? This same code worked when I was using Action Bar Tabs but I abandoned them when I realized they're not meant to work with the Navigation Drawer. Below is the stack trace:

```
 03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.testapp.slidingmenu.FragmentVenues.onActivityCreated(FragmentVenues.java:47)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-17 23:45:39.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2184):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace and indicate which line caused the NPE? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the static instatiator "newInstance" of FragmentVenues class is called before "onActivityCreated" is called? And is the return value from "newInstance" is same to the instance "onActivityCreated" is called on?

Comment: @IanGilI have added the stack trace, it occurs in FragmentVenues at line 47.

Comment: @JaemokLee No I am not, how can I make sure of that?

Comment: @Joshua Log f from newInstance, log this from onActivityCreated. And check if they are the same.

Comment: @JaemokLee I put a breakpoint in each of those methods and found that it is going to "onActivityCreated" before "newInstance" since it never reaches the latter's breakpoint.

Comment: @Joshua then, because "newInstance" is not called, and "setArguments" is not called. "getArguments()" in onActivityCreated will return null.  try call "setArguments" after FragmentVenues is inflated.

Comment: @JaemokLee I added a call to the newInstance method at the very beginning of the onActivityCreated and it is still returning a null.

Comment: @Joshua If you call "newInstance" method in "onActivityCreated", it just creates another instance and do not effect the instance which "onActivityCreated" called on. You should call "setArguments" before you call "getArguements" for the same instance. I do not know where you should put that call, because I do not know rest part of your code.

Comment: @JaemokLee Thanks for your comments, it helped me figure out what needed to be done!

Answer (score 0):

Implement Parcelable on both Venue Class and Fragment.

```
public class Venue implements Parcelable{

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: I tried this also and I am still receiving the same error.